# MPlatformAppInvitesJSDialog Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The Facebook App Invite Dialog of my iPhone app started to throw JS exception a couple days ago.  It had been working fine before that.  Look like a React exception:

```
MPlatformAppInvitesJSDialog?app_id=296240607391914&bridge_args={"action_id":"57FF266D-1861-4494-B9F…:179 Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.
at i (MPlatformAppInvitesJSDialog?app_id=296240607391914&bridge_args={"action_id":"57FF266D-1861-4494-B9F…:179)
at j (MPlatformAppInvitesJSDialog?app_id=296240607391914&bridge_args={"action_id":"57FF266D-1861-4494-B9F…:480)
at a (MPlatformAppInvitesJSDialog?app_id=296240607391914&bridge_args={"action_id":"57FF266D-1861-4494-B9F…:1583)
at require (MPlatformAppInvitesJSDialog?app_id=296240607391914&bridge_args={"action_id":"57FF266D-1861-4494-B9F…:149)
at k.render (MPlatformAppInvitesJSDialog?app_id=296240607391914&bridge_args={"action_id":"57FF266D-1861-4494-B9F…:1586)
at fb (MPlatformAppInvitesJSDialog?app_id=296240607391914&bridge_args={"action_id":"57FF266D-1861-4494-B9F…:1316)
at eb (MPlatformAppInvitesJSDialog?app_id=296240607391914&bridge_args={"action_id":"57FF266D-1861-4494-B9F…:1316)
at qb (MPlatformAppInvitesJSDialog?app_id=296240607391914&bridge_args={"action_id":"57FF266D-1861-4494-B9F…:1316)
at ic (MPlatformAppInvitesJSDialog?app_id=296240607391914&bridge_args={"action_id":"57FF266D-1861-4494-B9F…:1334)
at nc (MPlatformAppInvitesJSDialog?app_id=296240607391914&bridge_args={"action_id":"57FF266D-1861-4494-B9F…:1334)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reported to FB.  Turns out to be a confirmed bug:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/721787828000962